# Sending and receiving XML in SOAP request in Android

Tags: android, xml-serialization, ksoap2

I want to transform my XML and send it to Web Service which is receiving XML file in a form of String as a argument but I am receiving error by Web Service object reference not sent to instance of object any one who worked previously with sending XML to Web Service and receiving XML as response.

This is code which I am using:

```
    private static String Soap_Action = "http://portal.ordernet.net/RequestorderStringg";
    private static String namespace = "http://portal.ordernet.net";
    private static String methodName = "RequestorderString";
    private static String URL = "https://portal.ordernet.net/WebServiceorderNotice.asmx";

    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

    Element rootElement = document.createElement("dmi:ShipNoticeRequest");
    rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:dmi",  "http://portal.suppliesnet.net");

    document.appendChild(rootElement);



    Element ContactElement =  document.createElement("dmi:RequesterISA");         
    rootElement.appendChild(ContactElement);
    ContactElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("123456789012345"));

    Element articleElement = document.createElement("dmi:ShipDateRange");

    Element ShipDateFrom = document.createElement("dmi:ShipDateFrom");
    articleElement.appendChild(ShipDateFrom);
    ShipDateFrom.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2012-06-14"));

    Element ShipDateTo  = document.createElement("dmi:ShipDateTo");
    articleElement.appendChild(ShipDateTo);
    ShipDateTo.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2012-06-15"));

    rootElement.appendChild(articleElement);
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
    Properties outFormat = new Properties();
    outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
    outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperties(outFormat);
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement());
    OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
    transformer.transform(domSource, result);
    xmlString = output.toString();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
        }
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
    request.addProperty("RequestShipmentNoticeString", xmlString);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // envelope.headerIn.
    final HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(Soap_Action, envelope);
    SoapObject SoapResult = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    tv.setText("Status" + SoapResult);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("static", "Exception in making call to server");
    }
```

Comment: How is your web-service method defined? The WSDL would say exactly which element-names and namespaces are expected. It is not accessible from the internet, but you should be able to see it from: https://portal.ordernet.net/WebServiceorderNotice.asmx?WSDL

Comment: my webservice method takes xml and returns xml

Comment: SOAPAction: "http://portal.suppliesnet.net/RequestShipmentNoticeXML"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <RequestShipmentNoticeXML xmlns="http://portal.suppliesnet.net">
      <ShipNoticeRequestNode>xml</ShipNoticeRequestNode>
    </RequestShipmentNoticeXML>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>